# How to batch events in Esper based on a shared property

Tags: batch-file, correlation, esper, nesper

I am trying to batch together a bunch of events from a time window based on a matching property (User). Say, for example, the following events pass through esper in 1 second:

> User | File
>   A      | a1.sys
>   A      | a2.inf
>   A      | a3.sys
>   B      | b1.sys
>   B      | b2.sys
>   A      | a4.sys
>   B      | b3.inf

I want to batch the events by user and output the following 2 groups of events:

> Output 1
>   A      | a1.sys
>   A      | a2.inf
>   A      | a3.sys
>   A      | a4.sys
>   Output 2
>   B      | b1.sys
>   B      | b2.sys
>   B      | b3.inf

The key thing is that these groups need to be output as a collection and not one output per event. I need to emulate the type of response I would get from the below query (where events a, b and c are returned as a collection):

```
SELECT * FROM pattern[every a -> b -> c]
```

I just cant figure out how to shape such a query. I've tried the following but it doesnt batch the events together.

```
select * from ActivityEvent().std:groupwin(User).win:time_batch(5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is batch expression window that can compare events and release batches. It is described in [1].
[1] http://esper.codehaus.org/esper-5.0.0/doc/reference/en-US/html_single/index.html#view-win-exprbatch